# Retreive Information Around Key Words Javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a string that looks like this:

```
var string = "(This is an auto-generated string) and this is useless text I don't need";
```

What I would like to do is assign another variable the string INSIDE the parentheses so the second variable would look like this:

```
var selected_string = "This is an auto-generated string";
```

How would I retrieve data around the parentheses and then assign it to a variable in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to pull out any information between parens:

```
var regex          = /\((.*?)\)/;
var matched        = regex.exec(string);
var selectedString = matched[1];
```